# Determine the location of $(x_0, y_0)$ in terms of $h$ and $L$ using Calculus ideas

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

This is part of a Calculus 1 project and I am sorely stuck on this part.

Let's say you have a circle with center $(h,0)$ and radius $L$. This may or may not matter, but you can assume $h$ is positive and the tangent line of the point $(x_0, y_0)$ on the circle runs through the origin, $(0,0)$. "Determine the location of $(x_0, y_0)$ in terms of $h$ and $L$ using Calculus ideas."

Up to this point, I have found the equation for the tangent line at $(x_0, y_0)$ using implicit differentiation,  and I understand that the equation for this circle can be expressed as: $(x-h)^2+y^2=L^2$

I have tried to come up with equations to find $x_0=$ and $y_0=$ where I only use $h$ and $L$, but I'm not sure that's the right approach, let alone how to use calculus to find it. Any input is super appreciated, thank you!